# asset images not showing in release version of application in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, apk

I have made a list of images and using GridView.count to display the asset images and its working perfectly fine while debugging mode but when I release my application apk its not showing the images instead it show grey screen. please Guide me it take lot of my time but not solve yet
here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

class AnimalPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimalPageState createState() => _AnimalPageState();
}
class _AnimalPageState extends State<AnimalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 12,
          crossAxisSpacing: 12,
          children: <Widget>[
            alpha(1),
            alpha(2),
            alpha(3),
            alpha(4),
            alpha(5),
            alpha(6),
            alpha(7),
            alpha(8),
            alpha(9),
            alpha(10),
            alpha(11),
            alpha(12),
            alpha(13),
            alpha(14),
            alpha(15),
            alpha(16),
            alpha(18),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget alpha(var name) {
  var letters = 'assets/images/$name.jpg';

  return Expanded(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        image:
            DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('$letters'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
            Colors.black.withOpacity(.4),
            Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: InkWell(onTap: () {
        final player = AudioCache();
        player.play('$name.m4a');
      }),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: my apk image]

Comment: Is there any exceptions or can you show us the log?

Comment: it show some thing like this when i relase my app:C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.16.2\android\src\main\java\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.java:18: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;

Comment: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.16.2\android\src\main\java\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.java:26: warning: [deprecation] Handler() in Handler has been deprecated
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

Comment: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.16.2\android\src\main\java\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.java:31: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
    public static void registerWith(final Registrar registrar) {
                                          ^
3 warnings

Comment: 3 warnings
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     227.2s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (21.9MB).